# Finding the overall data from specific date using bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I am creating a query using bigquery that will calculate the overall number of data within 5 days from a specific date for each ID. So far I managed to get the result where the result return the data for each day (day 1 until 5), which means there are 5 dates in the result. However, what I want is actually  to return only 1 date which is the last date so it will be like that 1 date showing the overall data for the past 5 days from that specific date for each of ID.

Sample data:

[image]

Sample code:

```
  SELECT
   ID,
   Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lang_EN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'SN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lang_SN,
     FROM (
      SELECT 
      DATE(Timestamp) as Date ,
       ID, 
      CASE 
     WHEN Language in ('EN', 'English') THEN 'EN' 
     WHEN Language in ('MY', 'Malay')  THEN 'MY' ELSE Language 
     END AS Language,  
           FROM t
           WHERE Smooch_User_ID IS NOT NULL AND DATE(Timestamp) between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'
           GROUP BY   ID, Language, DATE(Timestamp) 
         )
          GROUP BY  ID,Date
```

Sample output:

So far, the query return the data for each date from day 1 to 5. How to make it so it returns the overall data from date 1 to 5 and also return column date only for the day 5's date like below (assuming day 1 is 2020-01-01 and day 5 is 2020-01-05).
[image]

Comment: Can you share the sample of desired output that you want to achieve?

Comment: You should present your initial input data as well as desired output. what is in your question right now looks to me as an intermediate data that does not help to understand your case. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one approach could be declaring variables, if you're using script, so that you could extract/tag your output against end_date in your interval. Eg.

```
    declare end_dt date default "2020-07-05"; -- this can be used as placeholder and replaced at run-time based on execution
    declare start_dt date default DATE_SUB(end_dt, INTERVAL 5 DAY);
    
    select 
      end_dt as ts_date, 
      id, 
      sum(CASE WHEN lang = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lang_EN, 
      sum(CASE WHEN lang = 'SN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lang_SN 
    from(
      -- sample data
      select cast("2020-07-01 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "A" as id, "EN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-01 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "A" as id, "EN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-01 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "A" as id, "SN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-02 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "B" as id, "EN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-02 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "B" as id, "EN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-02 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "B" as id, "SN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-02 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "B" as id, "SN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-03 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "C" as id, "SN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-03 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "C" as id, "EN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-03 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "D" as id, "SN" as lang
      union all
      select cast("2020-07-04 01:01:25.550 UTC" as timestamp) as ts, "D" as id, "EN" as lang
    ) where date(ts) between start_dt and end_dt
    group by 1,2
```

And output:

```
Row     ts_date     id  lang_EN     lang_SN      
1       2020-07-05  A   2           1    
2       2020-07-05  B   2           2    
3       2020-07-05  C   1           1    
4       2020-07-05  D   1           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is way more complicated than necessary.  You don't need a subquery at all, if you use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT ID, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT Language in ('EN', 'English') THEN DATE(timestamp) END) AS lang_EN,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Language in ('MY', 'Malay') THEN DATE(timestamp) END) AS lang_SN
FROM t
WHERE Smooch_User_ID IS NOT NULL AND
      DATE(Timestamp) <= DATE('2020-01-31') AND
      DATE(Timestamp) >= DATE_ADD(DATE('2020-01-31'), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY ID;
```

I think this also captures the date logic you are trying to implement.